# jQuery AJAX call with wrong type

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a question to the transmission method / type of the jQuery AJAX requests. I am aware that the type parameter tells jQuery what method to use (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE).

I have made myself a site where the user clicks a button and then new HTML content is inserted via AJAX. But oddly, I get results even when I tell jQuery to use complete nonsense as the type, e.g.

```
type: 'ABC'
```

Does jQuery have a fallback for unknown types?

When I check the console in Chrome it tells me that the AJAX loaded content has been transmitted via "ABC"-method.

How can I be sure about what transmission type has been used? How do I test?

Comment: It's up to the server to determine what methods are valid. I setup a test server and I can send `FOO` requests to it just fine.

Comment: There is indeed no fallback. If your request worked, your server doesn't validate the method used. If you were using a REST API, you'd certainly have had a 405 error code (Invalid method).

Comment: Looking through the source, jQuery doesn't seem to really care about what you send: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js

Comment: @Blender Checking the code I get the impression that unrecognized values for the type variable get overridden to the value "undefined".

Comment: @hurrtz: jQuery sent a `type: 'FOO'` request just fine for me. I can't see any special code for anything other than `GET` or `HEAD` requests.

Comment: @Blender In line 164 of the ajax.js there is the statement "// if "type" variable is undefined, then "GET" method will be used". Maybe that's the answer. Although I can't find the place where the type-variable gets checked against the correct REST-types, it seems that the call gets transmitted at least via GET.

Comment: @hurrtz: It defaults to `GET` if you don't pass a `type` parameter. There's no mention of `PATCH` or `DELETE` at all in the source tree, so I think jQuery just assumes that you know what you're doing and lets the server take care of deciding whether your method is valid or not.

Comment: @Blender Well, I guess that's the answer then. Had hoped for a different answer but I'll take it^^

Comment: @hurrtz: Don't take my word for it, but I remember reading somewhere that the HTTP 1.1 spec lets you define "custom" methods.

Comment: @Blender can you post your comment as the answer? It is in fact, the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

I understand it like this:

If your browser supports the type you're using it will use it. Since 'ABC' is not a supported HTTP method (in most browsers ;)) **jQuery defaults to 'GET'** instead.